# Display cursor on dragging amchart

Tags: javascript, ios, amcharts

I want to display an AMChartCursor on dragging through AMChart displayed with in a UIWebView. How can I implement this? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting panEventsEnabled property of Amcharts object to true, we can implement this functionality.